# Jenkins with Nunit test

Tags: jenkins

Am Configuring Jenkins with Nunit test but when I try to build then it fails, as below

I tried this links but no success

C:\Program Files (x86)\NUnit 2.6.2\bin>exit 0 
Recording NUnit tests results
FATAL: No NUnit test report files were found.

Comment: Can you post your job configuration or provide more info about your setup?

Answer (score -2):

Yahia, I try this form and work it

in  Jenkins project in **Action pos-building** in add new **new command windows batch** something like that (my jenkins is in portuguese).

and use this command lines

cd [path NUnit]\NUnit 2.6.1\bin\
nunit-console [path Nunit File test][nunit file test].nunit /xml=[path from your xml out][your xml out].xml

I hope to help.